# Fortran Bubble Sort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, fortran, bubble-sort

I'm with problems to compile a Bubble sort algorithm, I dont know what I'm doing wrong. I will appreciate so much if somebody helps me.

This is the code:

```
program bubble

   integer, dimension(6) :: vec 
     integer :: temp, bubble, lsup, j

      read *, vec !the user needs to put 6 values on the array
       lsup = 6 !lsup is the size of the array to be used

  do while (lsup > 1)
bubble = 0 !bubble in the greatest element out of order
      do j = 1, (lsup-1)
    if vet(j) > vet(j+1) then
    temp = vet(j)
    vet(j) = vet(j+1)
    vet(j+1) = temp
    bubble = j
      endif 
    enddo
    lsup = bubble   
enddo   
    print *, vet
end program
```

Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: His first sentence does suggest that he's having problems compiling the program. It would have been appropriate for him to have actually included those errors though. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had various issues in your code:

- a variable must not be name as the program
- the conditional lacked paranthesis
- typos: `vet` instead of `vec`

Here is a clean solution:

```
program bubble_test

  implicit none
  integer, dimension(6) :: vec 
  integer :: temp, bubble, lsup, j

  read *, vec !the user needs to put 6 values on the array
  lsup = 6 !lsup is the size of the array to be used

  do while (lsup > 1)
    bubble = 0 !bubble in the greatest element out of order
    do j = 1, (lsup-1)
      if (vec(j) > vec(j+1)) then
        temp = vec(j)
        vec(j) = vec(j+1)
        vec(j+1) = temp
        bubble = j
      endif 
    enddo
    lsup = bubble   
  enddo   
  print *, vec
end program
```

Your coding can be further improved... See [this example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort#Fortran).

Comment: Ok, my worst issue was to forget the parenthesis on the conditional. Other errors occured because I have translated the algorithm from my native language to english, excuse-me.
At least I've made no mistakes on logic. 
I didn't understand so much the code on rosettacode, where the numbers are coming ? I need to study more to understand the first "do" too.
Thank you so much!